# Array interpolation using python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have several 1D arrays with diferent sample rates. I would like to resample all the arrays.
Do you have any suggestion to do that?

The arrays are like that:

```
a=[-9494 -9496 -9498 ..., -9513 -9516 -9514]

b=[-9494 -9498 -9502 ..., -9506 -9510 -9514]
```

I've read the scipy.interpolate.interp1d documentation. But I didn't find any way to do it with the sampling rate.

Do you have any sugestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the sampling rate? Or do the arrays all span the same known time interval?

Comment: Yes, it's 50 Hz. The arrays don't have the same time interval, this is the next step, to fill the gaps in order to have arrays with the same time interval

Comment: Then you need to create an array of time values for each array with e.g. `np.arange` or `np.linspace`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create arrays of time values for each array and use them as the `x` values to `interp1d`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

a = np.array([-9494, -9496, -9498, -9513, -9516, -9514])
b = np.array([-9494, -9498, -9502, -9506, -9510, -9514])

dta, dtb = 1/4., 1/5.    # example sampling rates

na = len(a)
nb = len(b)
amax, bmax = (na-1)*dta, (nb-1)*dtb
ta = np.linspace(0, amax, na)
tb = np.linspace(0, bmax, nb)
ainterp = interp1d(ta, a)
binterp = interp1d(tb, b)

tmax = min(ta[-1], tb[-1])
target_sampling = 50
ngrid = int(tmax * target_sampling + 1)
tgrid = np.linspace(0, tmax, ngrid)
afine = ainterp(tgrid)
bfine = binterp(tgrid)

import pylab
pylab.plot(ta, a, 'o')
pylab.plot(tgrid, afine,'.')
pylab.plot(tb, b, 'o')
pylab.plot(tgrid, bfine,'.')
pylab.show()
```

Is this what you need?
[image]